# Need help interprete lmm result - One fixed effect one random effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, interpretation

I am investigating the difference in size between pike fry during their emigration period out from their nursery area. My hypothesis is that bigger fry tend to force smaller sized fry to migrate due to predation. The fry can chose to emigrate via two different creeks so I also want to know if fry choosing different routes also differ in size. So, I have three sampling sites (SITE). Since data sampling is from a long period when there is an on going new recruitment of fry, I use date as a random factor. There might be so that the effect of predation (thus forcing small fry to emigrate) sets in after a certain time point, therefore I also want to know the interaction effect between date and sampling site.

I used the lme4 package and the following code:

```
model1 <- lmer(LENGTH ~ SITE + (1|DATE) + (1|DATE:SITE), data=Fry)
```

Question 1: Is this right?

Here is a part of my output:

```
Random effects: 
 Groups        Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 DATE:SITE (Intercept)  16.17    4.021  
 DATE      (Intercept) 314.69   17.740  
 Residual              175.91   13.263
```

Question 2: Is the variance caused by sampling site = 314.69(314.69 + 16.17 + 175.91)?

Question 3: The variance caused by the interaction seems to be a lot smaller than the variance caused by both date and residuals. Is this to be interpreted as: there are no interaction effect?

Question 4: How can I visualize the interaction effects?

In my opinion, I get a pretty neat table to report my data from the following code:

```
stargazer(model1, type = "text", digits = 3, star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001), digit.separator = "")
```

Question 5: I get three asterisks indicating p<0,001 for my constant. That I do not have any such asterisk for mysite estimates is that the same as they are not god estimated?

As I suppose you realise I'm new to LMM and grateful for all help that I can get.
Thanks!

Comment: 1) What exactly is the variable `LENGTH` and how is it related to migration due to predation ? 2) How are the  different creeks represented in your data/model ? 3) how many dates do you have ? 4) how many measurements on each date ?

Comment: Hi Robert and thanks for helping!
1) LENGTH is the fry length in millimeter. Pikes are cannibalistic and intra-species predation is common among fry. So bigger individuals (born early or just lucky to reach food and grow fast), might force smaller individuals to migrate earlier.
2) the creeks are represented as different sites as well as fish caught within the nursery area. Thus 3 sites (creek1, creek2 and nursery area) from where data is collected.
3) I have 13 dates with catches but catches vary so I have between 1 and 30 measurements per date
//Oscar

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't just use a linear model with `lm(LENGTH ~ SITE * DATE)` ? It seems that would answer your research question without having the interpret variance components - particularlly since you have SITE as a fixed effect too.